# Alternative key for hardware damaged key on keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hardware-failure

The right arrow key on my laptop is damaged and it is a hardware problem. can I define another key for the right arrow? as I searched I just find a shortcut for other function but can I use shortcuts to address this problem? I am using ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Why not use the keyboard with NumLock off? This will let you use the numpad 4 as left arrow and numpad 6 as right arrow etc.

Comment: @harrymc Yes it is a good option but My laptop doesn't have Numpad!